# Piecewise Functions in R

Tags: function, plot

I'm trying to plot a piecewise function in R that is equal to -3 if x < 0, 1/3 * x^3 if x is between 0 and 5 (inclusive), and 4x otherwise. The function I've been running seems to work, but the plot returns an error message. The code I wrote is:

```
g <- function(x) {
   if (x < 0) 
      -3  # first component 
   else if (x >= 0 & x <= 5) 
      (1/3) * x #second component 
   else 
      4*x # third component
   }
```

Then when I try to plot it with

```
plot(g, -20, 20)
```

I get

```
Error in curve(expr = x, from = from, to = to, xlim = xlim, ylab = ylab,  : 
'expr' did not evaluate to an object of length 'n'
In addition: Warning message:
In if (x < 0) -3 else if (x >= 0 & x <= 5) (1/3) * x else 4 * x :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I can't quite figure out how to troubleshoot this, and the 'ifelse' function returned a dark black line when I attempted to plot it, which I'd prefer to avoid, so this seems to be my best bet.

I would greatly appreciate any insights.